# uninitialized constant Timer::Timers

Tags: ruby, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to do a task periodically, and I have seen [this](https://github.com/celluloid/timers). I have installed the `gem 'timer'` using `bundle install`

and then here is my `Timer` class:

```
require 'timers'
    class Timer

       def initialize
           timers = Timers::Group.new
           timers.every(5) { puts "Another 5 seconds" }
       end
    end
```

but when i run the class i face with the error:

```
   `require': cannot load such file -- timers (LoadError)
```

and here is the output of my `gem env` :

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.3/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin
     - /mnt/shared/bin
     - /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/.bin
     - /home/ubuntu/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /mnt/shared/sbin
     - /opt/gitl
     - /opt/go/bin
     - /mnt/shared/c9/app.nw/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
```

Comment: Did you `require 'timers'`?

Comment: It's not necessary to tell us you updated something. Stack Overflow shows us the last edit date, plus, after a certain number of user points the SO revision tracking becomes available.

Comment: How did you install the gem? Do you have multiple Rubies or gem sets installed? Copy the output of `gem env` and paste it into your question, formatting it for readability.

Comment: You are using RVM. Bundler can get confused if you have multiple Rubies installed, and you can get confused if you have multiple Rubies with multiple Bundlers. I'd recommend stepping through each of your Rubies, including the system owned one, and see what `gem list timers` says.

Answer (score 0):

This error tells us the code you are trying to load is not on the LOAD_PATH. When you `require 'timers'` you are telling Ruby to search the LOAD_PATH for a file called `timers.rb` and it cannot be located. Installing the gem does not put the gem on your load path.

It sounds like you are not using [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) to manage your dependencies. Once you start depending on 3rd party code, you really should start using Bundler. It will put all the code you need on the LOAD_PATH and provide a ton of other helpful features.

If you are just messing around, one option you can do is:
`ruby -I <path/to/timers/lib>`

This will allow Ruby to locate [timers.rb](https://github.com/celluloid/timers/blob/master/lib/timers.rb)

Comment: i just copy the **ruby -I path/to/timers/lib** but it doesn't work.